# ¿Como aplicar estilos de materialize-css a una aplicación en express js?

Tags: nodejs, express

Tengo la siguiente aplicacion de `nodejs` usando `expressjs`:

### app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const main = require("./main/main");
const port = 3000;
const path = require("path");

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname+"/static/css")));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname+"/static/js")));

app.use("/", main);

app.use("/contacts", contacts);

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Online"));
```

### main.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const path = require("path");

router.get("/", (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+"/main.html")));

module.exports = router;
```

### main.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection"/>

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h1>Hi</h1>
     <div class="card-panel teal lighten-2">This is a card panel with a teal lighten-2 class</div>
      <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Cuando ejecuto la aplicacion el documento me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/static/css/materialize.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

GET http://localhost:3000/static/js/materialize.min.js 404 (Not Found)

Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/static/js/materialize.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

**¿Como puedo aplicar el estilo materialize-css en express js?**

Comment: El problema no es el estilo, sino que el navegador se niega a usar los ficheros que recibe del servidor: el servidor le dice que el contenido es HTML cuando realmente es CSS, y lo mismo te está pasando con el fichero Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teniendo la siguiente estructura:

```
static |
       | css
       | js
main   |
       | main.js
       | main.html
app.js
```

**Solución:**

*Los cambios solo deben hacerse en app.js pues de all se desembocaran los cambios en todo el app.*

1) En primer lugar, se debe servir el directorio raiz de los estaticos, no una ruta, por tanto:

**Esto:**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname+"/static/css")));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname+"/static/js")));
```

**Pasa a esto:**

```
app.use(express.static("static"));
```

*Donde static es la carpeta donde están los estáticos*

2) En cuanto al html se debe colocar solo la carpeta que esta dentro del directorio raiz, es decir:

**Esto:**

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection"/>
```

**Pasa a esto:**

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection"/>
```

*Donde unicamente colocamos los directorios que estan dentro de la raiz, en este caso /css y /js, tambien podria existir /img y /fonts*